# How to concat a variable in relay fragment

Tags: graphql, relay

Similar when we're using `${Component.getFragment('fragment')}`, is there a way I can simply concat a variable with a valid query inside a relay fragment? similiar to this:

```
const query = `
    allFriends {
        id
    }
`

Relay.createContainer(Component, {
    fragments: {
      viewer: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Query {
          allUsers {
            id
          }

          ${query}

        }
      `
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RelayQL plugin allows you do this by defining the fragment as a variable. [See example here](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-ql.html#inline-fragments) on the RelayQL documentation page or see example below:

Here I create a fragment on the **Email** type and I can inject that fragment into any field of type **Email** such as the Interview#email or the User#email:

```
const emailFragment = Relay.QL`
  fragment on Email {
    from
    to
    body
    subject
  }
`;

export default Relay.createContainer(Component, {
  initialVariables: {
    emailId: $emailId
  },
  fragments: {
    interview: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Interview {
        recordId
        email {
          ${emailFragment}
        }
      }
    `,
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        recordId
        email(id: $emailId) {
          ${emailFragment}
        }
      }
    `
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I really didn't find that in the docs :/ That solved my problem.